Proving a distribution is not infinitely divisible
I'm trying to show the following:

Show that the distribution on $\mathbb R$ with density $f(x) = \frac{1-\cos(x)}{\pi x^2}$ is not infinitely divisible.

The characteristic function of this distribution is $\varphi(t) = (1-|t|)^+$. If the distribution were infinitely divisible, then $\varphi_n(t) = [(1-|t|)^+]^{1/n}$ would be a characteristic function of a probability distribution, since $\varphi_n(t)^n = \varphi(t)$. (Actually this is "if and only if.") By Bochner's theorem, since $\varphi_n(t) \geq 0$ for all $t$, these are characteristic functions of probability distributions $\mu_n$, and the $n$-fold convolution of $\mu_n$ is the distribution with density $f(x)$. This contradicts the statement of the exercise. Am I going wrong somewhere? If so, is there a better way to show this?

EDIT: As it was pointed out in the comments, $\varphi_n(t) = [(1-|t|)^+]^{1/n} \geq 0$ does not imply positive semidefiniteness in Bochner's theorem. You actually can show $\varphi_n(t)$ is not positive semidefinite in the way Bochner's theorem requires. However, this exercise came from the book's section on stable distributions (section 16.2 of Achim Klenke's "Probability Theory: A Concrete Introduction", 3rd ed), so I'm wondering if there's a way to do it using stable distributions somehow.

That's not what "positive-definite" means in the statement of Bochner's theorem.

@QiaochuYuan you're right. I thought it implied positive definiteness though. I see I was wrong however

Lukacs, Th 5.3.1: the characteristic function of an infinitely divible distribution has no real zeros.

You could be a little less terse.  For instance, you could mention that the Lévy–Khintchine theorem has a bearing on this question.
